# Zero conditional vs first conditional

Tags: sentence-meaning, conditional-constructions

I have some problems with zero and first conditionals . Sometimes ı can't distinguish them.

1-***I could see if anyone wanted to break in .***

About the context : The speaker has a shop and he says this sentence after leaving his shop on its own.And he is worried about the shop.

So the sentence 1 is "past real conditional" right? meaning it is "zero conditional".

2-***Let me know if you need anything.***

Again I don't know if the sentence 2 is "zero conditional" or not .

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write your sentence is:

> If you need anything, then let me know.

*Let* is being used imperatively.  Intuitively one would likely associate this to present tense, making this a "zero conditional."  But *will* also can be used to suggest an imperative.

> If you need anything, then you will let me know.

But this isn't really future tense, even  though it looks like it

Using [this site](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/type-1-conditional/) as a reference, the difference between zero and type 1 conditionals is:

> In type 1 conditional sentences, you can also use modals in the main clause instead of the future tense to express the degree of certainty, permission, or a recommendation about the outcome.

And that's what you're doing when you add *will* above.

Other modals work, to express the degree of "certainty" ... of imperativeness:

> If you need anything, then you { should | would | could | must } let me know.

If you're going to use this "zero, first, second, third" model of conditionals, it seems imperatives straddle both zero and type 1.

Comment: Thank you , do you have any idea about the sentence -1 ?